# Whats the appropriate method of acquiring consistent response for innerHTML data using $.get across different browser platforms?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

Given the following code:

```
var hostUri = window.location.origin + '/GuestValidator.asmx/GetReservationInfo?resvNo=' + reservationno;
$.get(hostUri, {}, function (response) {
      var data = response.documentElement.innerHTML;
}
```

If executed within a Chrome browser, the expected result returns a comma-delimited string of values within the innerHTML property of the documentElement object.

However, if the same code is executed using IE 11 or Edge there is no innerHTML property on the documentElement. It comes back as undefined.

But I can revise my code to response.documentElement.childNodes[0].data when executed within IE and get the same result that was present in Chrome using innerHTML.

I haven't tested the code with other browsers but I suspect they will likely have differences also.

So how can this code be revised to acquire what would be the innerHTML value within Chrome across all browsers without having to execute separate code based on the browser?

## EDITED FOR CLARITY

This is an excerpt of the web method. It is returning a generic list of type string. It doesn't matter whether or not I return a JSON object.

```
var arry = new List<string>();
var blockedOrderDays = 3;
var blockedDay = String.Empty;
var noOrderDays = String.Empty;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
var svclient = new ServiceClient();
var result = svclient.GetReservation(reservationNo);

var details = result.Reservation.ArrivalDate;
var arrivalDt = formatDate(details);
while(blockedOrderDays != 0)
{
    blockedDay = formatDate(details.AddDays(-blockedOrderDays));
    arry.Add(blockedDay);
    noOrderDays += blockedDay + ",";
    -- blockedOrderDays;
    ++x;
}
arry.Add(arrivalDt);
noOrderDays = noOrderDays + arrivalDt;
return noOrderDays;
```

Comment: so `$.get` is converting it to HTML fragment? seems odd it would have a documentElement. Weird you are not returning a data format that is easy to parse and not worry what is being returned.

Comment: @epascarello not certain I understand your comment. I am returning a string array which works perfectly well for giving an explicit return type if I were using ASP.NET pages using a $.ajax call and a code behind calling a WebMethod. This however is being called from an HTML page and the get method is using a local asmx web method. So maybe I didn't thoroughly explain the issue? Unless I'm missing something, the $.get method will always return an xhr object.

Answer (score 0):

After spending some additional time and effort on getting this code to work with a reasonable level of continuity across browser platforms. The following modification appears to have resolved the issue.

```
var hostUri = window.location.origin + '/GuestValidator.asmx/GetReservationInfo?resvNo=' + reservationno;
$.get(hostUri, {}, function (response) {
if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") !== -1) || (!!document.documentMode === true))
    prohibitOrderDates = response.childNodes[0].textContent;
else
    prohibitOrderDates = response.children[0].innerHTML;
    var data = response.children[0].innerHTML;
}
```

Alternatively, though not specific to the answer. A shortened version of the call can be:

```
var hostUri = window.location.origin + '/GuestValidator.asmx/GetReservationInfo';
$.get(hostUri, { resvNo=reservationno }, function (response) {
if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") !== -1) || (!!document.documentMode === true))
    prohibitOrderDates = response.childNodes[0].textContent;
else
    prohibitOrderDates = response.children[0].innerHTML;
    var data = response.children[0].innerHTML;
}
```

So the response.children[0].innerHTML is the appropriate call to retain browser continuity for most every browser I've tested and IE always seems to be the exception to the rule. Even Microsoft Edge follows the standard. IE seems to be an odd ball for ever keeping standard.